# Copying a C# code from a book(C# .0 for dummies), can't get the expected outcome

Tags: c#, string, concatenation

The expected result is that the user can enter a string and it builds a sentence until the user exits. When my strings are added together there is no space between the strings.

I have tried adding `+ " "` after sentence and it did not work. any ideas? sorry new to c#

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Each line you enter will be  " + "added to a sentence until you " + 
    "enter EXIT  or QUIT");
    //Ask the user for input;  continue concatenating
    //the phrases input until the user enters exit or quit (start with an empty sentence).
    string sentence = "";
    for (; ; )
    {
        //Get the next line.
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a string ");
        string line = Console.ReadLine();
        //Exit the loop if the  line  is a termiantor.
        string[] terms = { "EXIT", "exit", "QUIT", "quit" };
        //compare the string  entered to each of the legal exit commands.
        bool quitting = false;
        foreach (string term in terms)
        {
            //Break  out of the for loop if you  have a match.
            if (String.Compare(line, term) == 0)
            {
                quitting = true;
            }
        }
        if (quitting == true)
        {
            break;
        }
        //Otherwise, add it to the sentence.
        sentence = String.Concat(sentence, line);
        //let the user know how she's doing.
        Console.WriteLine("\nyou've entered: " + sentence + " ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine(" \ntotal sentence:\n " + sentence);

    //wait for user to acknowledge  results.
    Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to terminate...");
    Console.Read();
}
```

Comment: This would be a good opportunity to learn to use the [debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2019). When you step through your code one step at a time the problem should be easy to find.

Comment: More like "C# by Dummies", but try`sentence = String.Concat(sentence + " ", line);`.

Comment: thanks the ``` sentence = String.Concat(sentence + " ", line); worked. Any books worth recommending? the code I posted was exactly how it was in the book =(

Answer (score 1):

Try adding in the space as part of the overloaded methods of `String.Concat` that joins 3 strings

```
sentence = String.Concat(sentence, " ", line);
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings in C# are immutable, meaning you get a new copy of the string every time you change it.

When you do:

```
Console.WriteLine("\nyou've entered: " + sentence + " ");
```

You're creating a string that will be passed to `Console.WriteLine`, but not changing your original `sentence` variable.

You can simply add the space when you concat the new string with `sentence`:

```
sentence = String.Concat(sentence, line, " ");
```

Answer (score 0):

`String.Concat(sentence, " " + line);`